# How can I assign a number to access assigned array value?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm storing results in a multidimensional array, some values are identified by variables with a numeric value ex. $end1 = "2017-01-08"; Each date has about 10 categories under it that store a numeric value.
I need to loop thru all the values under $end1 to get a total.

this works:

```
foreach($results[$key][$end1] as $type => $amount) {
    $total1 += $amount[$value];
}
```

but now I have a bunch of these foreach statements - one for each total I need - and I'd like to consolidate them into one block, but I am having trouble getting the variable name correct.

this does not work:

```
    for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
        $target = "\$end$i";
        $targettotal = "\$total$i";
        foreach($results[$key][$target] as $type => $amount) {
            $targettotal += $amount[$value];
        }            
    }
```

How do I fix/define $target and $targettotal so the array values are accessible?

Comment: Is this an option: $target .= "\$end$i";
        $targettotal .= "\$total$i"; and why are you escaping the dollar sign \$ ?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean but do you want to print the output or save the output of $total and $targettotal in an array? And do want to access it, e.g. $total[$i] = 'output';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following demonstration, note the evaluation of **$targetVarName** in the next line by prepending it with another dollar sign.

```
<?php

$item1 = 'aaa';
$item2 = 'bbb';
$item3 = 'ccc';
$item4 = 'ddd';
$item5 = '333';

for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {

    $targetVarName = 'item' . $i;

    echo $targetVarName .' => '. $$targetVarName . "\n";
}
```

This will output something like:

```
item1 => aaa
item2 => bbb
item3 => ccc
item4 => ddd
item5 => 333
```

Comment: Cheers! if it helped please don't forget accepting it as the answer :)